# Tkinter pyimage doesn't exist

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I know there are lot of similar questions, but there aren't any simple enough that I am able to understand. I have the following code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        canvas = Canvas(master)
        canvas.pack()
        self.pimage = Image.open(filename)
        self.cimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pimage)
        self.image = canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.cimage)


filename = full_filename
root = tk.Tk()
x = MainWindow(root)
mainloop()
```

and I get the following error:

```
TclError: image "pyimage36" doesn't exist
```

I've read some stuff about the image objects getting garbage cleaned but I don't quite understand it.

Comment: Show full error message - there is more information. Is "pyimage36" a filename or what ?

Comment: I have been having this problem too.  I seem to only have this issue when I am using Spyder. I get the error when using Spyder both in windows and in Linux (Raspbian).  When I use Idle on the Pi or Pycharm on windows I don't get this behavior.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Figured it out. For some reason, while running in the debugger, if any previous executions had thrown errors I get the "pyimage doesn't exist" error. However, if I restart the debugger (or no previously executed scripts have thrown errors), then the program runs fine.

Comment: Some might disagree. For example. In networking it is common practice to restart a server after some amount of time or if it encounters an error (rather than trying to fix the error). This is because starting from a known state is much more predictable.

Comment: Thanks for that! That was the problem when using appJar.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error message when using spyder  3.3.6 the only way i could get the .png file to load and display after getting the 'Tinker pyimage error ' was to go to the Console and restart the kernel. After that i worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

*(Python 3.8)*

If you are using a IDE with a console(such as Spyder) just call `root.mainloop()` in the console.
Odds are that you have a bunch of partially loaded tkinter GUI's that never managed to be executed due to an error that prevented the `root.mainloop()` function from being run.
Once you have run the `root.mainloop()` a bunch of GUI's will likely appear on screen. After you have closed all those GUI's try running your code again.
[Image of multiple Tkinter GUI's appearing on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AXWy.png)

Read more about `mainloop()` here: https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-mainloop/

Answer (score 2):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")

img = Image.open('Paste the directory path')
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

lbl = Label(root, image=bg)
lbl.place(x=0, y=0)

mainloop()
```

I was getting the same error. Try this code this will help you.
Additionally, in case if you create a button and use it to open other window, then there use **window = Toplevel()**, otherwise it will again show the same error.

Comment: On Spyder 5.1.5 you would have to restart the console each time there is an error in your code(as you test)

Answer (score 0):

> From programmersought

image “pyimage1” doesn’t exist
Because there can only be one root window in a program, that is, only one Tk() can exist, other windows can only exist in the form of a top-level window (Toplevel()).

Original code

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.TK()
```

Revised code

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Toplevel()
```

Keep other code unchanged

https://www.programmersought.com/article/87961175215/

Comment: This solved the problem for my student’s code. Had to use a ‘TopLevel’ object for secondary windows.