# _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage" doesn't exist

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Before I start, yes I have looked through all the previously asked questions I just can't seem to find the answer,
So I have this code I'm using with Tkinter and the code runs perfectly fine on its own.

I then create another file to call this particular file and I get the `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage" doesn't exist`.

I have no idea why it works on its own but fails when called.

The calling class:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
#import all classes
from tests.rpm import *
from tests.bst import *
from tests.gdt import *

#results to store on cloud
RPMresult = BSTresult = GDTresult = VLresult = 0

def RPMCALL():
    root = Tk()
    w = 500 # width for the Tk root
    h = 500 # height for the Tk root
    # get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
    # calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    # set the dimensions of the screen
    # and where it is placed
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    RPMcall = RPM(root,6)
    root.mainloop()
    global RPMresult
    RPMresult=RPMcall.getresult()

def BSTCALL():
    root = Tk()
    w = 500 # width for the Tk root
    h = 500 # height for the Tk root
    # get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
    # calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    # set the dimensions of the screen
    # and where it is placed
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    BSTcall = BST(root,6)
    root.mainloop()
    global BSTresult
    BSTresult=BSTcall.getresult()

def GDTCALL():
    root = Tk()
    w = 500 # width for the Tk root
    h = 500 # height for the Tk root
    # get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
    # calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    # set the dimensions of the screen
    # and where it is placed
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    GDTcall = GDT(root,6)
    root.mainloop()
    global GDTresult
    GDTresult=GDTcall.getresult()


RPMCALL()
BSTCALL()
GDTCALL()
```

The class giving me an error:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
import os

class GDT:
    def __init__(self,master,cage):
        filepath=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.cage = cage
        self.master=master
        self.count = 0
        self.frame1 = Frame(self.master,width=500,height=475)
        self.frame1.pack(side=TOP)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.master,height=25,width=500)
        self.frame2.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.nextbtn = Button(self.frame2, text= "Next", command = self.next)
        self.nextbtn.place(x= 250, y= 12.5, anchor= "center")
        self.opt_selected1 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected2 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected3 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected4 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected5 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected6 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected7 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected8 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected9 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected10 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected11 = IntVar()
        self.opt_selected = [self.opt_selected1,self.opt_selected2, self.opt_selected3, self.opt_selected4,self.opt_selected5, self.opt_selected6, self.opt_selected7, self.opt_selected8, self.opt_selected9, self.opt_selected10]
        self.opts1 = self.create_options(self.frame1,0)
        self.opts2 = self.create_options(self.frame1,1)
        self.opts3 = self.create_options(self.frame1,2)
        self.opts4 = self.create_options(self.frame1,3)
        self.opts5 = self.create_options(self.frame1,4)
        self.opts6 = self.create_options(self.frame1,5)
        self.opts7 = self.create_options(self.frame1,6)
        self.opts8 = self.create_options(self.frame1,7)
        self.opts9 = self.create_options(self.frame1,8)
        self.opts10 = self.create_options(self.frame1,9)
        self.createq()
        self.q = [filepath+"/GDT/GDT1.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT2.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT3.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT4.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT5.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT6.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT7.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT8.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT9.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT10.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT11.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT12.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT13.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT14.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT15.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT16.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT17.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT18.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT19.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT20.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT21.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT22.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT23.png", filepath+"/GDT/GDT24.png"  ]
        self.qn =0
        self.age = cage
        self.agegroup = [3,6,8,11,13,17,20,24]

    def create_q(self,frame1,qn):
       filepath=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
       photo = Image.open(filepath+"/GDT/GDT1.png")
       photo = photo.resize((500, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
       self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
       photolabel = Label(frame1,image=self.render)
       photolabel.image = self.render
       photolabel.pack()
       return photolabel

    def checkans(self):
        self.qn+=1
        if self.opt_selected11.get() == 1:
            self.count+=1
        if self.qn>= self.agegroup[self.age-3]:
            self.result()
        else:
            self.opt_selected11.set(0)
            self.dispq(self.qn)

    def dispq(self,n):
        photo = Image.open(self.q[n])
        photo = photo.resize((500, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
        self.ques['image'] = self.render

    def result(self):
        filepath=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath+"/GDT/GDT.csv")
        X =df.iloc[:, 0:8]
        result = X.iloc[self.count, self.age-3]
        print(str(result)) #printing percentile
        self.frame3.pack_forget()
        if result<=10:
            strid = "Definitely below required: Intellectual Disability"
            ID = True
        elif result<=20:
            strid = "Below required: Intellectual Disability"
            ID = True
        else:
            strid = "Normal"
            ID =False
        self.frame1.destroy()
        self.frame1 = Frame(self.master,width=500,height=450)
        self.frame1.pack(side=TOP)
        if ID == True:
            self.frame1.configure(background='firebrick2')
        else:
            self.frame1.configure(background='spring green')
        labelid = Label(self.frame1, text = strid)
        labelid.place(x= 250, y =225, anchor = "center" )
        self.nextbtn['command'] = self.nexttest

        self.returnval = int(result)


    def nexttest(self):
        self.master.quit()

    def createq(self):
        n = 0
        q1 = Label(self.frame1,text="Palmer hold on writing instruments:")
        q1.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q2 = Label(self.frame1,text="Spontaneous scribble:")
        q2.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q3 = Label(self.frame1,text="Purposive horizontal scribble:")
        q3.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q1 = Label(self.frame1,text="Makes dots:")
        q1.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q1 = Label(self.frame1,text="Tripod hold on writing instruments:")
        q1.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q1 = Label(self.frame1,text="Purposive vertical scribble:")
        q1.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q1 = Label(self.frame1,text="Imitates vertical strokes:")
        q1.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q1 = Label(self.frame1,text="Extends tail to dots in different directions:")
        q1.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q1 = Label(self.frame1,text="Imitates horizontal strokes:")
        q1.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")
        n+=1
        q1 = Label(self.frame1,text="Traces outline of objects/ palm on paper:")
        q1.place(x=0,y=23.5+23.5*2*n,anchor="w")


    def create_options(self,frame,n):
        b_val = 0
        b = []
        btn = Radiobutton(frame, text="Yes",variable=self.opt_selected[n],value=b_val+1)
        b.append(btn)
        btn.place(x=490,y=(23.5+23.5*2*n),anchor="e")
        return b

    def next(self):
        for i in range(0,9):
            if self.opt_selected[i].get() == 1:
                self.count+=1
        self.frame1.destroy()
        self.frame3 = Frame(self.master, width =500, height=25 )
        self.frame3.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.frame1 = Frame(self.master,width=500,height=450)
        self.frame1.pack(side=TOP)
        self.nextbtn['command'] = self.checkans
        btn = Radiobutton(self.frame3, text="Yes",variable=self.opt_selected11,value=1)
        btn.place(y= 10, x =250, anchor = "center")
        self.ques = self.create_q(self.frame1, self.qn)

    def getresult(self):
        return self.returnval

root = Tk()
w = 500 # width for the Tk root
h = 500 # height for the Tk root
    # get screen width and height
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
    # calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    # set the dimensions of the screen
    # and where it is placed
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
GDTcall = GDT(root,6)
root.mainloop()
```

Exact error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/adishrao/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py",
line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "/Users/adishrao/Desktop/Intellectual_disability/Amaatra/tests/gdt.py",
line 163, in next
    self.ques = self.create_q(self.frame1, self.qn)   File "/Users/adishrao/Desktop/Intellectual_disability/Amaatra/tests/gdt.py",
line 56, in create_q
    photolabel = Label(frame1,image=self.render)   File "/Users/adishrao/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line
2763, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)   File "/Users/adishrao/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line
2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist
```

Comment: You need to provide an MCVE. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BIG NO GO, multiple `root = Tk()` leads to unexpeced behavior. Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same problem, but only while using spyder (no problems using pydev in eclipse). I found for myself two solutions, that worked for me.

Solution 1: 
Goto Tools => Preferences and chose IPython console on the left. In the IPython console menu chose the Graphics Tab and disable the checkbox "Active support" at the top (Support for graphics). Save and restart you Kernel before you run the code

Solution 2:
Goto Run => Configure and chose "Execute in an external System terminal", Save and run the code

As mentiond above, both solutions worked for my issue.

Comment: THis still requires to kill the COnsole every now and then or when getting the same dreadful "pyimage" doesn't exist error, but thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thats something I also get in Spyder (I read Anaconda in your error message so I am guessing you are using Spyder). 
I get this problem after trying to run my code an getting an error message.

Set the part where you use that image as an comment and start like that. After that close and start again with that image. Should work now.

Also also don't use multiple root = Tk() as said in the comments!

See also in this question:
[Tkinter pyimage doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274072/tkinter-pyimage-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score -1):

@Marcel S. solution 1 does not work for me but solution 2 works. It appears to be a problem related to Spyder only.

The TclError message 'image "pyimage x" doesn't exist' happens when:

1. You attempt to create a image, **AND**
2. the previous run with spyder results in any error message.

So my solution is to run again without any error message, for example, by simply bypassing the line of code that creates image.

Then you can debug and run again.

Answer (score -1):

I installed pyimage and that solved my problem.

```python
pip install pyimage
```